# Difference between (Both. . .and ) and ( Not only . . . but also )

Tags: grammar

I have a question about (Both. . .and )  and  ( Not only . . . but also )

What is difference between those two? Or I can use any of them?

> I like both cats and dogs.

> Not only do I like cats but also dogs too.

Comment: The only difference is that in 'Not only... but also', the second item is a new idea (perhaps the previous conversation had been about cats only), or something unexpected.

Comment: The two structures could easily mean the same thing, but not here. First, we have *also* and *too*, too. Second, the sentence says that dogs like cats, because of the placement of *do I like*. The matching form would be *I like not only cats but also dogs* or *Not only do I like cats but I like dogs too*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it comes to BOTH-AND, the verbs can't be singular, but for NOT ONLY-BUT ALSO, the verb agrees with the noun closest to it.

Examples for BOTH---AND

> Both Ravi and Rani are in love with each other. --> Correct
>
> Both Ravi and Rani *love* each other. --> Also correct
>
> Both Ravi and Rani *loves* each other. --> Wrong

Examples for NOT ONLY---BUT ALSO

> Not only Ravi but also Shiva loves Rani. --> Correct
>
> Not only Ravi but also Shiva love Rani. --> Incorrect
>
> Not only Ravi but also Raja and Shiva love Rani --> Correct
>
> Not only Ravi but also Raja and Shiva loves Rani. --> Incorrect
>
> Not only Ravi and Shiva but also Raja loves Rani. --> Correct
>
> Not only Ravi and Shiva but also Raja love Rani. --> Incorrect